# how to iterate over an array - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array stored into a localStorage using the json.stringify method. Now, i retrieve the localstorage into an array. How can iterate over the array. Below is what i have done so far

With the code below, the table is appended with the values as

```
<td> 448239239,232324201 </td>
```

But i want to the data to show as

```
<td> 448239239</td>
<td> 232324201</td>
```

What could be the issue with my code below ?

**File.js**

```js
var items = [];
items.push(localStorage.getItem('numbers'));
if (items != '') {
  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
  });
}
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('numbers')` produces a *string*. So you seem to get an array with a single element `[ "448239239,232324201" ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the value of `localstorage` as a string. So you need to split as comma delimiter

```
var items = [];
    localStorage.setItem('numbers', '448239239,232324201');
    items = localStorage.getItem('numbers').split(',');

    if (items != '') {
      $.each(items, function(index, value) {
        $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>');
      })
    }


    <table id='myTableID2' border='1px solid green'>
      <tbody id='user-id2'> </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need parse the JSON first, before created individual rows for each array element:

```
var items = localStorage.getItem('numbers');

if (items) {
    JSON.parse(items).forEach(function(v) {
        $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td>'+v+'</td></tr>');
    });
}
```

Comment: Iterate over an array with a single element -> during the only iteration you get split the value -> loop over the split value. To me, it seems the first two steps are completely useless.

Comment: @VLAZ Right. Misunderstood OP's original intention. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will first have to parse the value fetched from the localStorage as you can only store strings in local an session storage - try something like this:

```js
var items = localStorage.getItem('numbers')

if (items) {

  items = JSON.parse(items)

  $.each(items, function(index, value) {
    $('#myTableID2 #user-id2').append('<tr><td>' + value + '</td></tr>')
  })

}
```